# Laravel Auth loging out malicious user

Tags: authentication, laravel

I'm implementing a banning system. I have an admin view where the admin can ban users. I want to log out a user if the admin bans him in that moment. Something like `Auth::logout($user)`. Is that possible?? Or do I have to add a filter to all my routes to check if the logged user is banned.

Comment: The `logout()` method does not take any parameters.

Comment: I know... That's why I'm asking this... That was just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters are the way to go. It's easy and clean to solve this problem, see my example below.

if user is banned at any point it will logout user at his/her next request, you can redirect user with Session flash message, your login code works as it is.

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
         if (Request::ajax())
         {
             return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
         }
         else
         {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
         }
 }
else
{
    // If the user is banned, immediately log out.
    if(Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->bannedFlag)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flash('message','Your account is banned, please contact your administrator             to active your account');

        // redirect to login page
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
});
```

and for your routes use group routes

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
        //use your routes 
});
```

Comment: I think I was overthinking it. Thanks.